# libswscale5:amd64

Tags: apt, 18.10

I got the following message when I was installing mcrypt on Ubuntu 18.10:

```
dpkg: error processing package libswscale5:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

How do I re-install libswscale5?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libswscale5
```